# Polynomials that preserve nonnegativity

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, polynomials, positivity, semialgebraic-geometry

A polynomial $p \in \mathbb{R}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ is said to be *[positive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_polynomial)* on a subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ if $p(x) > 0$ for every $x \in S$. The polynomial $p$ is called *nonnegative* if $p(x) \ge 0$ for every $x \in S$.

It is known that if $p \in \mathbb{R}[x]$, then $p$ is nonnegative on $\mathbb{R}$ if and only if $p = q^2 + r^2$, with $q,r \in \mathbb{R}[x]$.

I am wondering what is known about the set $\mathscr{P} := \{ p \in \mathbb{R}[x]\mid p(x) \ge 0,~\forall x\ge 0 \}$—since $f(x) = x \in \mathscr{P}$, it is clear that so this set is distinct from the globally-nonnegative case above.

Any insight/references would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A minor quibble: The first sentence states a definition of positive polynomials on subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n.$ Then the entire rest is only about non-negative polynomials on subsets of $\mathbb{R}.$

Comment: @AaronMeyerowitz: edited; thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is known as the Pólya-Szegö theorem:
[image]

Note that $\Sigma = \Sigma_n := \{ p \in \mathbb{R}[x] \mid p~\text{SOS}\}$, in which 'SOS' stands for *sum of squares*.

A reference for the result: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-0-387-09686-5_7

Comment: The proof is strange. Where are factors with complex roots?

Comment: Are the nonreal roots absorbed in the polynomial $s_0$? That's the only thing I can come up with.

Comment: Ah,  I see: it proves a weaker statement,  not $f^2 +xg^2 $,  but $f^2 +g^2 +xh^2 +xq^2 $

Answer (score 17):

Such a polynomial may be represented as $q^2 +xr^2 $ (proof: this is true for all irreducible divisors which have degree 1 or 2, and the set of polynomials of this kind is a multiplicative monoid by Euler identity.)

Strictly positive for $x>0$ polynomials may be represented as $q(x)/(x+1)^n$, where $q$ has non-negative coefficients.

Comment: The second description of $\mathscr{P}$ is wrong, take e.g. $p(x)=(x-1)^2$. If the polynomial $p(x)(x+1)^n$ would have non-negative coefficients, then it couldn't vanish in $1$.

Comment: @Fedor: do you have a reference for this or did you just come up with that?

Comment: Indeed,  thank you!  This is true for strictly positive on $(0,+\infty)$ polynomials. Fixed.

Comment: @PietroPaparella for which of two facts? Actually I know both for many years, but finding a suitable reference is another task.

Comment: A reference for the first fact would be great — thanks!

Comment: I only know a reference for the second fact (a theorem by Polya), which in contrast to the first fact isn't trivial.

Comment: @PeterMueller it is not much harder: you multiply the quadratic trinomial $x^2 +ax+b$ by $(x+1)^n$ and write down the condition that all coefficients are non-negative.